# How to compress a ppm image in C

Tags: c

for a exercice i must compress a ppm image without including a library that does it for us.
For example before compression:

```
6
6
6
2
2
```

After compression :

```
6: 3
2: 2
```

I made a Array but I don't know how to do the compression algorithm

```
int get_nb_lin(char *str)
{
    int nbr = 0;

    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        if (str[i] == '\n')
            nbr++;
    }
    return (nbr);
}

int get_len_lin(char *str)
{
    int nbr = 0;

    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\n'; ++i) {
        if (str[i] == '\0')
            return (nbr);
        nbr++;
    }
    return (nbr);
}

char **buf_to_arr(char *str)
{
    int nb = get_nb_lin(str);
    int bn = get_len_lin(str);
    char **tab = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (nb + 2));
    int k = 0;
    int l = 0;

    tab[k] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (bn + 2));
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (str[i] == '\n') {
            tab[k][l] = '\0';
            (str[i + 1] != '\0') ? k++,
            tab[k] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (bn + 2)), l = 0 : 0;
        }
        tab[k][l] = str[i];
        l = (tab[k][l] == '\n') ? l - 1 : l;
        l++;
    }
    tab[k][l] = '\0';
    tab[k + 1] = NULL;
    return (tab);
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What you seem to want is called **R**un **L**enght **E**ncoding (RLE). Now when you know the terms you should be able to find resources, tutorials and algorithms to help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data range is limited and small (which it seems like it is, image pixels are in the range of 0->255), then you can use this method which is very fast and efficient:

```c
void compress(size_t size, const int *data)
{
    int count[256] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) ++count[data[i]];

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
        if (count[i] != 0) printf("%d:%d\n", i, count[i]);
}

int main()
{
    int array[5] = {6, 6, 6, 2, 2};
    compress(5, array);
    return 0;
}
```

It creates a variable for each possible value and calculates its count as the loop goes through the array.